# Get dynamic radio ID and value (jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery

We have dynamic ID's generated from a database like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="brand1" value="1">
<input type="radio" id="brand1" value="2">
----
<input type="radio" id="brand2" value="1">
<input type="radio" id="brand2" value="2">
```

How can I get/alert, through a click on a radio button, which ID it is?

(I guess my error is in the first line: 'input#brand'.)

```
$('input#brand').live('click',function() { 
    var radiovalue = $('input[name=brand + id]:checked').val()
    alert(radiobuttonID + radiovalue);
});
```

Comment: Your markup is invalid. IDs must be unique and `live` method is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use something like this to get id:

```
$('input[id^=brand]').live('click',function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});​
```

and this to get value:

```
$('input[id^=brand]').live('click',function() {
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
});​
```

Notice that we can put a live click handler on all of the elements that start with (`^=`) "brand".

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/WDUKZ/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=radio]' , function() {

     alert('Radio Button ID  is : ' + this.id + ' - Value is : ' + this.value);
})
```

Also make sure you have unique id's on the page..

It's better to assign a single class to all the radio buttons on the page for which you want to handle this event..

```
$(document).on('click', '.myradio' , function() {

         alert('Radio Button ID  is : ' + this.id + ' - Value is : ' + this.value);
    })
```

Doing so will make you code cleaner and easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

Use the [attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/attribute), this will select all input with id that start with `brand`.

```
$('input[id^=brand]').live('click',function() { 
    alert(this.id + ' ' + this.value);
});
```

Also as of jQuery 1.7 [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was deprecated, use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.  Also ids should be unique, in your markup you have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: @KJS he's right.  The name attribute should be the same for radio buttons, not the ID. +1

Comment: Thanks for the info guys!
ps. The elements with the same ID are intended. It works now, but upgrading to jQuery 1.7> will be a sweet project as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Correct your selector please. $('input#brand') means that you looking for INPUT with exact id "brand".